# Unmatched Route when using shared routes with array syntax on expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

#### Which package manager are you using? (Yarn is recommended)

yarn

#### Summary

Hello,

I have set up a basic expo typescript project using `npx expo init` with `expo-router` & `expo-dev-client` installed and I'm running this app on the **Web**.

Whenever i try to navigate to a shared route that has been created in the `app/` directory using the [array syntax](https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/shared-routes/#arrays) I consistently get:

```
Unmatched Route
-------
Page could not be found. Go back.
[http://localhost:8081/events/(manage)/1234]

(http://localhost:8081/events/1234)
```

In my `app` directory I have created a file layout like so:

```
app/
  index.tsx
  _layout.tsx

  events/
    (manage, preview)/
      [eventID].tsx
       _layout.tsx
```

When I set my hrefs to be `/events/1234` they work but then how do I differentiate between the sub-view to which I want to gain access e.g: (manage, preview).

When I get to the page successfully (without (manage) or (preview) in the href) my segment log (in `(manage, preview)/_layout.tsx`) looks like `events/(manage,preview)`

I'm hoping I've just massively misinterpreted something here which is usually the case.

Any help would be amazing!

Peace!

#### Minimal reproducible example

#### app/index.tsx

```js
import { Link, useRouter } from "expo-router";

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return <>
    <Link href="/events/(manage)/1234">
      I don't work
    </Link>
    <Button title="I don't work" onPress={() => router.push("/events/(manage)/1234")} />

    <Link href="/events/1234">
      I work but am confused...
    </Link>
    <Button title="I work but am confused..." onPress={() => router.push("/events/1234")} />
  </>
}
```

#### events/(manage,preview)/_layout.tsx

```js
import { Slot } from "expo-router";

export default function DynamicLayout({ segment }) {
  console.log(segment);

  return <Slot />;
}
```

#### events/(manage,preview)/[eventID].tsx

```js
import { useLocalSearchParams, usePathname } from "expo-router";

const Page = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const localSearchParams = useLocalSearchParams();

  return (
    <Text>
      {pathname} : {localSearchParams.eventID}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Github issue: https://github.com/expo/router/issues/805
Expo forums post: https://forums.expo.dev/t/unmatched-route-when-using-shared-routes-with-array-syntax/72951